# Throwing and catching a string

Tags: c++

I'm just writing my errors as words.
Should I catch them as `char* v`, `char v` or `const char* v`?

```
try{
    int choice = 1
        if(choice != 2)
            throw choice;
}
catch(char* v){
    if (v == choice)
cout << "Error: choice != 2."
}
```

Comment: Don't. Use `std::exception` and derived classes.

Comment: In your code you are throw-ing int, not a string!?

Comment: The question is about strings, you throw an int and catch a char pointer... If you want to provide an error message, use `std::runtime_error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
try
{
    int choice = 1;
    if(choice != 2)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("choice != 2");
    }
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

std::exceptions are the preferred objects to be thrown and
the error location knows best to provide a description of what is happening.

Comment: I think you should remove the condition `v == choice`, since neither `v` nor `choice` are defined at this place and you want to generally show the exception's "what"-message, independent of which error occurred, right?

Comment: @leemes: agree on that one. I copied it from the original question

Comment: I removed the `v == choice`

Comment: Now only two semicolons were missing -- added them. ;)

Answer (score 9):

You should catch an int since you are throwing an int